# C++ program crashing on weird input

Tags: c++, string

Im coding huffman compression and it works fine for all exteded ascii(0-255) but when I open non text file like mp3 that has somethink like that inside:

> ťîxł¸ H…W]`9M          ČČ               ˇ˘Ł¤Ąxw

it crashes. I tested and it is not because of the size it is because of the input data.

It crashes on file save, heres the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<=contents.length();i++){
    newString +=kod[contents[i]];
}
saveFile("test_nowy.txt", newString);

bool saveFile (string name, string contents)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(name.c_str());
    file << contents;
    file.close();

}
```

I also need to say that despite passing all earlier steps(calculating codes etc) the results are wrong. It seems like my program doesn't understand those characters.

Comment: It doesn't "work fine for all extended ASCII (0-255)" if you have a character type that can't hold values greater than 127.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you are right and thats the problem. But i have no idea how can I use different type than char and still assign it to string

Comment: Why did you tag this with c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing negative indices of your `kod` array.  Try

```
kod[contents[i] & 0xFFu]
```

See http://ideone.com/2LvmKW

Also fix the overrun that billz spotted.

Comment: is that really the best way to cast it to an unsigned value?

Comment: @Chris: Did you check the linked test?  Casting to `unsigned` won't have the desired effect.  Also, this code is shorter and won't overflow the 256x256 array if run on a system where `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: no, casting to unsigned *will* have the desired effect in the 8-bit char case - casting between signed and unsigned types does not change the bits, but only their intrepretation.  But you do have a point if targeting something with a greater than 8 bit char, such as the TI DSP I used to write for.

Comment: @Chris: casting to `unsigned char` will have the desired effect.  Casting to `unsigned` does not, because the value is widened first, undergoing sign extension, and then reinterpreted as unsigned.

Comment: I didn't say *unsigned* as in an alias for an *unsigned int*, I said an "unsigned value" - that's descriptive rather than keyword usage of the word "unsigned", which in this case would mean an *unsigned char*

Comment: Well, even with `CHAR_BIT == 8`, I still think `& 0xFFu` is a lot nicer than `static_cast<unsigned char>()`

Comment: Hey it says, invalid operands of types `char[256]' and `unsigned int' to binary `operator&'

Comment: @zarcel: You must have either (1) put the `& 0xFFu` in the wrong place (it belongs inside the square brackets for `kod`) or (2) the code you showed in the question is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You are accessing out the boundary of a string which is **undefined behavior**.

```
for(int i=0;i<=contents.length();i++)
             ^^
```

should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<contents.length();i++)
             ^^
```

BTW, it will be a good time to learn debugger. Capture the exact point where the program crashes and find out why.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. As I said it works for regular text files so It doent seem to be a problem(I checked, it still crashes). I don't want to rewrite contents to newString, but char array named kod to newString.

Comment: Characters in `contents` are not directly appended to `newString`; they are used as indices into `kod`. So I don't think the last point holds.

Comment: can I see how do you define kod? maybe kod is not big enough to hold all string?

Comment: @billz its char kod[256][256], What about char not able to hold negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You say it works for all characters from 0..255, but not for these characters, that would imply you're using something other than an 8 bit char.  If so, you're probably indexing outside the range of kod.

Comment: @BenVoigt is char unsigned by default?

Comment: @zarcel: That's implementation-specific.  If you need an unsigned value, use `unsigned char` and not simply `char`.

Comment: The use of the character value as an index into an array *strongly suggests* that an unsigned char is desirable.

Comment: I'm confused, how is signed-ness an issue if zarcel's code actually works for 0..255?

Comment: @Mike: Pretty sure it doesn't.  He said it works for text files, i.e. character codes from 0-127.  And "non text file" fails.